# Git Merging Selected Items From Develop Master

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have develop branch with many projects, now I want to create pull request from develop to Master branch.
But, I dont want to merge all the projects that I have in develop..

For instance, develop has 'project1','project2','projectNew'. Master has no projects.

In this case I want to merge only 'projectNew'..

How can I do this?

What is the simple way for this?

Comment: Why do you have multiple projects within one repository?

Comment: Because some people in the past decide that this is the right way to work with git..
They collect each project with it's dependency in repo
@jonrsharpe

Comment: They were wrong. It's going to be an awkward task, you'll have to selectively merge manually.

Comment: Is there no script for merging in this way? 
@jonrsharpe

Comment: I doubt it, it's an unusual use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wanted to state that this isn't directly possible through `git`. Git is made to have a 1-to-1 project-to-repo.

That being said, there is a solution I can think of, but it's tedious.

```
git checkout master
git log --pretty=oneline -- projectNew/
# Now open a new terminal 
git cherry-pick {sha-hash}
```

You'll have to cherry-pick each hash one by one, but it will at least allow you to do what you want.